# File in Nginx alias location accessible, but PHP file_exists returns false

Tags: nginx, php

I add an alias location in Nginx. All files accessible in the browser but when I check in PHP file_exists return false.
My Nginx video location configuration:

```
location /videos {
   alias D:/avan/film1; #drive D is outside Nginx drive.
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$mainFileName360 = "videos/a.mp4";
if (file_exists($mainFileName360))
echo $mainFileName360; else echo "false";//result is false.
?>
```

File is accessable from my site. ie:
http://avantube.test/videos/a.mp4

Comment: PHP does not know anything about your alias. It expects the relative filesystem path from the location of the script file.